# How to scrape all text or paragraph using beautiful soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i want to scrape all text in paragraph. Below is the link and code that i have made:
note: currently want to extract 10 pages first.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import re
import time

#create a list
Title = []
Paragraph = []

#scrape the first 10 page data(the no of pages can be changed)
pages = np.arange(1, 10)

for page in pages: 
  
    page = requests.get("https://www.malaymail.com/news/money?page=" +  str(page))
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
    
    list_all = soup.find_all('div',class_='data')
    
    for h in list_all:
        title=h.find('h2').text
        parag=h.find('p',attrs={'class':'summary d-none d-md-block'})
        
        Title.append(title if title else '')
        Paragraph.append(parag if parag else '')
    
#create a dataframe
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Title':Title,
                   'Content':Paragraph})
df
```

current output:
[image: below is the current output that i get]

so, expected output that i want is:

1. Currently, value at column 'Content' not scrape full text. What i want is full text and want remove sign '[]'
2. Currently, first 18 rows not return Content value. why it happen?. and how to fill in this part too.

Comment: really appreciate the help for this :)

Answer (score -1):

Use find_all('p'), it will return list of all finded paragraphs over whitch you can iterate